# How to load Google API client library with SvelteKit

Tags: google-api, svelte, workbox, sveltekit

I'm new to SvelteKit and trying to find out how to load the Google client library for Javascript.

Google [tells me](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/samples.md) to do it like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <script>
      function start() {
        // Initializes the client with the API key and the Translate API.
        gapi.client.init({
          'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
          'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/translate/v2/rest'],
        }).then(function() {
          // Executes an API request, and returns a Promise.
          // The method name `language.translations.list` comes from the API discovery.
          return gapi.client.language.translations.list({
            q: 'hello world',
            source: 'en',
            target: 'de',
          });
        }).then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.result.data.translations[0].translatedText);
        }, function(reason) {
          console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
        });
      };

      // Loads the JavaScript client library and invokes `start` afterwards.
      gapi.load('client', start);
    </script>
  </head>
```

The problem is that SvelteKit doesn't allow 2 or more script tags on a page (I don't want it to be the layout page).

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
    gapi.client.init({...
</script>
```

This results in follwing error message:

```
A component can only have one instance-level <script> element
```

As my intention is to create a progressive web app (PWA) using Workbox I don't want to import the Google library as described [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/nodejs) because the package containing this library would become too heavy.

Any ideas how to load the Google client library? Maybe there's a Workbox way to do it? Couldn't find a SvelteKit example on Google or YouTube.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `svelte:head` tag allows you to add resources to the document head when a component is loaded. This example should work:

```
<script>
  const start = async () => {
    // Initializes the client with the API key and the Translate API.
    // @ts-ignore
    gapi.client.init({
      'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
      'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/translate/v2/rest'],
    }).then(function() {
      // Executes an API request, and returns a Promise.
      // The method name `language.translations.list` comes from the API discovery.
      return gapi.client.language.translations.list({
        q: 'hello world',
        source: 'en',
        target: 'de',
      });
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.result.data.translations[0].translatedText);
    }, function(reason) {
      console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
    });
  };

  const initializeGapi = async () => {
    gapi.load('client', start);
  }
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" on:load={initializeGapi}></script>
</svelte:head>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When doing a build I get following error: "'initializeGapi' is not defined". The on:load part can't reference to the const initializeGapi

Comment: I am not sure what you copied. But if you insert this into your index.svelte it runs fine. At least it does on my PC.

Comment: Strange. Have to figure out what the problem is on my side. I don't have the code on index.svelte but on another page but that shouldn't make a difference imho

Comment: I got it working by adding this at the top of the .svelte file `<script context="module">
  export const ssr = false
</script>`

Answer (score 2):

I've made something like this.
Save it as GoogleMap.svelte to your lib folder. and use it like this;

```
<GoogleMap
 {map}
 globally
 on:load={() => {
  console.log('MAP SAYS IM LOADED');
 }}
/>
```

- Map is a reference object
- `globally` defines it to `window.map`

```
    <script>
        import { onMount } from 'svelte';
        import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
        const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    
        //import mapStyles from './map-styles'; // optional
    
        export let globally = false;
        export let map;

        let src = '';
        const key = ''; 
    
        // @ts-ignore
        let container;
        let zoom = 8;
        let center = { lat: 37.5742776, lng: 43.7260158 };
    
        onMount(() => {
            Object.assign(window, {
                mapLoaded: () => {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    map = new google.maps.Map(container, {
                        zoom,
                        center
                        // styles: mapStyles
                    });
                    dispatch('load', true);
                    if (globally) {
                        Object.assign(window, { map });
                    }
                }
            });

            //Assign
            src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${key}&callback=mapLoaded`;
        });
    </script>
    
<!-- This is tailwind css class change with whatever fits to your case. -->
    <div class="w-full h-full" bind:this={container} />
    <svelte:head>
        {#if src}
            <script {src}></script>
        {/if}
    </svelte:head>
```